# How to debug my roulette JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript

I'm a student trying to learn JavaScript. I'm trying to code a random 
array with an event handler and button to return a result in this 
little game. We are required to use some of the structure below. In 
researching the subject, I've seen there are other ways to write 
this.

The developer tools and the validate (WC3) don't show any errors. Can anyone tell me the error of my ways?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HW_6 Random Russian Roulette</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script language="Javascript">
        function shoot() {
            var iShot = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
            var trigger = new Array();
            trigger[0] = "ch1 lucky";
            trigger[1] = "ch2 click";
            trigger[2] = "ch3 BANG!";
            trigger[3] = "ch4 click";
            trigger[4] = "ch5 lucky";
            trigger[5] = "ch6 Lucky";

            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("shoot").onclick = shoot;
                document.getElementById("divOutput").innerHTML = trigger;
            }

            alert("trigger[shoot]");
        }
    </script>


    <form>
        <input type="button" value="It's loaded..." id="shoot">
        <div id="divOutput">shoot</div>
        ;
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so, what is the problem - describe what you expect and how it differs from what your code does - perhaps if you laid out your code with proper indentation the MAIN issue would become obivous

Comment: Are you attempting to choose a random index in the array? It looks like you already have that index with the `iShot` variable.

Comment: HI @sher s , Welcome to stackOverflow, If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

#### Bug in your code:

`document.getElementById("shoot").onclick = shoot;` you need to use `shoot()` to call a function. Do the following to add a click event on button (pure js):

```
  var st = document.getElementById("shoot");
  st.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    shoot();
  });
```

#### Some improvement:

`var iShot = Math.floor(Math.random() * trigger.length);` this choose an random index from array since it use array length as the base.

define array you could do this in js

`var trigger = ["ch1 lucky", "ch2 click", "ch3 BANG!", "ch4 click", "ch5 lucky", "ch6 Lucky"];`

#### (Solution) Two options:

#### Option 1 (pure javascript)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  //do work
  var st = document.getElementById("shoot");
  st.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    shoot();
  });

  function shoot() {
    var trigger = ["ch1 lucky", "ch2 click", "ch3 BANG!", "ch4 click", "ch5 lucky", "ch6 Lucky"];
    //get a random element from array
    var iShot = Math.floor(Math.random() * trigger.length);
    //out put result now
    document.getElementById("divOutput").innerHTML = trigger[iShot];
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" id="shoot">It's loaded...</button>
  <div id="divOutput">shoot</div>
</form>
```

#### Option 2 (use jQuery)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#shoot').on('click', function() { shoot(); });

  function shoot() {
    var trigger = ["ch1 lucky", "ch2 click", "ch3 BANG!", "ch4 click", "ch5 lucky", "ch6 Lucky"];
    var iShot = Math.floor(Math.random() * trigger.length);
    $("#divOutput").html(trigger[iShot]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <button type="button" id="shoot">It's loaded...</button>
  <div id="divOutput">shoot</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone! I got it to work by putting my function call/onload outside the script and incorporating the .innerHTML to a div output.